# How to design objects for simple school application

Tags: java, oop, object

I want to create simple school application that provides grades,notes,presence,etc. for students,teachers and parents. I'm trying to design objects for this problem and I'm little bit confused - because I'm not very experienced in class designing. Some of my present objects are :

```
class PersonalData() {
    private String name;
    private String surename;
    private Calendar dateOfBirth;
    [...]
}

class Person {
    private PersonalData personalData;
}

class User extends Person {
    private String login;
    private char[] password;
}

class Student extends Person {
    private ArrayList<Counselor> counselors = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Counselor extends Person {
    private ArrayList<Student> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Teacher extends Person {
    private ArrayList<ChoolClass> schoolClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This is of course a general idea. But I'm sure it's not the best way. For example I want that one person could be a Teacher and also a Parent(Counselor) and present approach makes me to have two Person objects. I want that user after successful logging in get all roles that it has (Student or Teacher or (Teacher & Parent) ). I think I should make and use some interfaces but I'm not sure how to do this right. Maybe like this:

```
interface Role {
}

interface TeacherRole implements Role {
    void addGrade( Student student, Grade grade, [...] );
}

class Teacher implements TeacherRole {
    private Person person;
    [...]
}

class User extends Person{
    ArrayList<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Please if anyone could help me to make this right or maybe just point me to some literature/article that covers practical objects design.

Comment: Shouldnt this be on programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a system like this, it seems like you can create a User class that has all the personal properties as well as account information in it:

```
public class User
{
   // personal properties
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private Calendar dateOfBirth;

   // account properties;
   private String login;
   private String password; // note that string may be more convenient than char[]

   // role properties
   public ArrayList<Role> roles;
   ...

   public bool hasRole(Role role) // or isInRole(Role role)
   { // implementation here. }
}
```

Then you have your Role object:

```
public class Role
{
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Note that there is only one role class that could be any of teacher, student, parent, etc. Since the Role class is generic, we do not have functions in it such as addGrade(), since that is specific to a teacher.

When the user logs in with proper credentials, such a system would already know the roles associated with the user. Usually, role-specific tabs, links, and other UI elements would show (or not show) depending on the role. This is where you check to see if the user logged in is in a particular role (user.hasRole(...)). For each UI element whose visibility is determined by the role, you would have to have an if (user.hasRole(...)).

In regard to the composition issues, this system is one that heavily relies on relationship between objects. Let's consider the relationship between students and counselors - a counselor has students assigned to him/her. Likewise, any given student has many counselors. You've got a many-many relationship which calls for a structure that keeps track of the combination of unique student-counselor pairs:

```
public class StudentCounselor
{
     public User student;
     public User counselor;
}
```

And who keeps track of all of this? Most likely the system itself, not another user.

```
public class SystemAdministration
{
     public static ArrayList<StudentCounselor> studentCounselors = new ArrayList<StudentCounselor>();

     public static void addStudentCounselor(User student, User counselor)
     {
         //  Check to see first that the student-counselor combo doesn't exist

         studentCounselors.addItem(student, counselor);
         // addItem may not be the precise name of the function in ArrayList.
     }

     // function to obtain all students of a counselor
     public static ArrayList<User> getStudentsOfCounselor(User counselor)
     {
         // iterate through the studentCounselors ArrayList and pick only
         // the Student-Counselor whose counselor is the same counselor
         // as the one passed into this function.
         // Then extract the student property out of the fitting 
         // Student-Counselor.
         // Return the list of students. 
     }

     public static ArrayList<User> getCounselorsOfStudent(User student)
     {
         // Similar as above, but the other way around.
     }

}
```

You would do similar for your other relationships - parent-student, teacher-sections, etc. The SystemAdministration class is NOT a role, but the entity responsible for providing you with all the data.

As a suggestion, consider the Section object:

```
public class Section
{
    public User teacher; // who teaches it
    public Course course; // what is the subject, because > 1 teacher might teach the same one.
    public TimeBlock timeBlock; // when is this section administered?
    public Venue venue; // what room or what facility
}
```

You would have to create the TimeBlock and Venue classes. This structure, when put in an ArrayList will be able to answer the questions: "As a teacher, what sections will I teach?" and that answers the question "what subjects, when, and where will I teach them?"

As for the student, you'll need the StudentSection "combo" class:

```
public class StudentSection
{
    public Section section;
    public User student;
}
```

When put in an ArrayList of the SystemAdministrator class, now you can iterate through the list to extract what sections are assigned to a student (aka, the student's schedule), and likewise, who are the students of a given section.

Note that we don't have a list of related items in the User class except roles. To obtain any data, info about the logged-in user and his/her roles should be sufficient as long as you have all the data and access functions in a global (in this case SystemAdministration) structure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" design; it all depends on how you plan to interact with these classes/interfaces. Try to sketch the methods you intend to call, in the most natural possible way, and work from those to understand what a good layout for your classes could be. If you feel brave, try learning the Test Driven Development methodology; writing actual unit tests before the "real" code can help make your mind on the class structures.

As a general suggestion, try to avoid inheritance, and favor composition instead. Having an array of `Role` elements is a step towards that direction; try to understand you plan to interact with these roles, and add methods accordingly.